# Filtering on window functions in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, filter, where-clause, common-table-expression, window-functions

I generated a CTE called `mycte` from 5 select statements using union to combine them. The output looks like this for a particular job:

| ID | JOB_ID | STATUS | BASE_ID | PERCENTAGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20DA | GBR01 | 0 | 12 | 20 |
| 21DA | GBR01 | 0 | 12 | 30 |
| 21DA | GBR01 | 0 | 14 | 50 |

For every unique `JOB_ID` the sum of the percentage must be 100%.

To test my CTE, I used:

```sql
SELECT JOB_ID, SUM(PERCENTAGE) AS myTOTAL
FROM myCTE
GROUP BY JOB_ID
HAVING SUM(PERCENTAGE) <> 100
ORDER BY SUM(PERCENTAGE)
```

The output showed that not all sum up to 100 because of dirty data in the database. I then attempted to extract 2 different tables, one for PERCENTAGE = 100% and the other for <> 100%.

Since the columns I needed to extract for the new table are ID, JOB_ID, STATUS, BASE_ID and PERCENTAGE, I then applied

```sql
SELECT
    ID, JOB_ID, STATUS, BASE_ID, PERCENTAGE,
    SUM(percentage) OVER (PARTITION BY JOB_ID, BASE_ID, ID) AS PERCENTAGE_SUM
FROM
    mycte
```

Unfortunately where clause will not work on window function.

Question: how do I extract only `ID, JOB_ID, STATUS, BASE_ID, PERCENTAGE` from `mycte` where sum of the percentage = 100?

Comment: *Please* when posting actually look at the preview of it before hitting the Submit/Post Question answer; if you had you would have seen quite how malformed your content was.

Comment: But you don't have a CTE - don't misuse terminology. You have a table named mycte that you perhaps generated using a CTE but it is NOT a CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the sample data it looks like you need to partition by `JOB_ID` only:

```
WITH mycte AS (
    ...
), cte2 as (
    SELECT
        ID, JOB_ID, STATUS, BASE_ID, PERCENTAGE,
        SUM(percentage) OVER (PARTITION BY JOB_ID) AS PERCENTAGE_SUM 
    FROM mycte
)
SELECT *
FROM cte2
WHERE PERCENTAGE_SUM = 100
```